# How can i get the time of a TimePicker in this format -> "08:00:00"?

Tags: android, parsing, timepicker

i have a android timepicker, and i need to get his time in java code, and transform it into a string with this appereance: "08:00:00" (hours, mins, secs)

can someone help me to do it in a easy way?

code example will be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = format.format(date); // date is a long in milliseconds
```

Comment: also it doesn't work, it gives me illegal argument exception, is because i have to pass a timepicker to format.format(); and you are passing a date :S

Comment: I assume you know how to get time in milliseconds from the picker, then just use formatter to get the String. You can substitute `date` with `time` in the code snippet - nothing will change, since both are expected to be a number of milliseconds.

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to transform a time, without date, in miliseconds... can you tell me?

Comment: (picker.getCurrentMinute() * 60 + picker.getCurrentHour() * 60 * 60) * 1000

Answer (score 12):

```
TimePicker t = new TimePicker(this);

String formattedTime = "";
int hour = t.getCurrentHour();
String sHour = "00";
if(hour < 10){
 sHour = "0"+hour;
} else {
 sHour = String.valueOf(hour);
}

int minute = t.getCurrentMinute();
String sMinute = "00";
if(minute < 10){
 sMinute = "0"+minute;
} else {
 sMinute = String.valueOf(minute);
}

formattedTime = sHour+":"+sMinute+":"+"00"; // Sorry you can't get seconds from a TimePicker
```

Answer (score 8):

[`TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) has 2 methods available to get the set time. [`getCurrentHour`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentHour()) and [`getCurrentMinute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentMinute()).

So outputting this as a string shouldn't be too hard.

```
String s;
Format formatter;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// tp = TimePicker
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.setCurrentMinutes());
calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND); //reset seconds to zero

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
s = formatter.format(calendar.getTime()); // 08:00:00
```

By the way, lowercase `hh` will get you a 12 hour clock.

Comment: I just realized I set the format to `:ss` when you'd probably want `00` and not current seconds. You can change the format to `"HH:mm:00"`

Answer (score 2):

Just use SimpleDateFormat to format date and time .

```
Calendar cal=new Calendar();
SimpleDateFormat frmDate=SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String s=frmDate.format(cal.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat frmTime=SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:SS");
String t=frmTime.formate(cal.getTime());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [`DateUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html), very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = format.format(date); // date is a long in milliseconds
```